# Cannot start a windows service developed in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services

Well, it works on my own computer where I have visual studio installed. I install the exe file with installutil and the service works fine. But when I install it on another computer where only the framework is present, I still can install it with installutil BUT I can't start it. I get something along this `Could not start the Search service on Local
computer.  Error 1053: The service did not respond to the
start or control request in a timely fashion.`

And in application event log there is this:

> The description for Event ID ( 0 ) in
>   Source ( .NET Runtime ) cannot be
>   found. The local computer may not have
>   the necessary registry information or
>   message DLL files to display messages
>   from a remote computer. You may be
>   able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to
>   retrieve this description; see Help
>   and Support for details. The following
>   information is part of the event: .NET
>   Runtime version 1.1.4322.2379-
>   Search.exe - Common Language Runtime
>   Debugging Services: Application has
>   generated an exception that could not
>   be handled.
>
> Process id=0x10e4 (4324), Thread
>   id=0x1168 (4456).
>
> Click OK to terminate the application.
>
> Click CANCEL to debug the
>   application..

What do you think I should do?

I'm using visual studio 2003 and programming in VB.NET. Framework both on my computer and the other one is 1.1.4322 (my own computer has also newer ones installed).

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing during the service startup?  Most likely is that something in there isn't working and forcing the service to fail.

I often have the startup just kick off a timer (10 seconds or so nothing too long) so that the service can offically start and then have the timer take care of functionality needed.  You'll have a better chance of logging any issues that way as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "(my own computer has also newer ones installed)", do you mean you have a newer version of the .Net Framework installed? You may need to try installing the same exact versions of the .Net Framework on both computers. If you run the .exe by double-clicking on it, does it throw an exception?